# Generate Unique Sequence

Tags: vb.net

I have 8 different single digit variable with either 0 or 1 value.
I need to create concurrent string by placing together all those 8 digit to create an unique sequence variable and then need to add all those unique sequence variable in a list or array.

for an example;

each of sequence will be like **00000000** or **11111111** or **01010101** or **01101100**

trying to find the better way to write a function to genrate all unique sequnces.
What I tried...

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports AlphaSequence.My
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim str As String = Nothing
        Dim obj As JArray = Me.GetSequence(Me.NumericUpDown1.Value)
        
        Debug.Print(obj.ToString)
    End Sub

    Friend Function GetSequence(ByVal face As Integer) As JArray
        Dim Seq As JArray = New JArray
        Dim str As String = Nothing
        Dim data As String = Nothing
        For a = 0 To 1
            str = ""
            For i = 0 To face
                str = str & a
            Next
            Seq.Add(str)
        Next
        Return Seq
    End Function
End Class
```

I am missing something, this loop is not right and not generating value as expected, Can any one help me to write a better code to get expected result ?

Comment: _this loop is not right_ could you update your question with the details of exactly what this means.  It would also help if you could include an put value and expected output.  And finally, why JArray?  Are you intending this to be serialised via Json at some stage?

Comment: I need an unique key for each sequence which must be created with 1 & 0 only for up to 8 division. I have a mesh object (3D Mesh) which having 8 faces, the faces can be hidden or shown. that's why I need 8 character length Unique key for each sequence (permuted, without repeataion and ordered). each character's position defines face number and each character value defines True or false. I need string defining face number and face value . For example: 01010101 = Face1,3,5,7 is hidden, and face 2,4,6,8 are shown. string collection and serialized json both needed for desktop and web interface.

Comment: Input value is a digit, 1 to 8 as face number, when input value is 2, that mean the sequence string length is 2, the output list is [00,01,10,11]. same way when input is 7 output string leangth is 7, when input is 8 output string leangth is 8. Need Unique sequence collection in a list or array in ordered when I have the collection in JArray, I can convert to Json for web interface.

Comment: To describe in a better way, I am sharing Google sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Bb9Wuy0fDbH85n7nEdDHlyVrKZeAwz3maSA73nvbyjw/edit#gid=0